# error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’): in counting number of inversions in an array using mergesort

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, debugging, mergesort

I am trying to write this code to count the number of inversions in an array using merge sort technique. I took reference from [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-inversions/). Even though I am not explicitly playing with pointers I am getting this error.

> error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)

Below is my code.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int mergeSort(int arr[], int temp[], int l, int r){
    int invcount = 0;

    if(l<r){
        int m = (l+r)/2;
        invcount += mergeSort(arr, temp, l, m);
        invcount += mergeSort(arr, temp, m+1, r);

        invcount += merge(arr, temp, l, m, r);
    }
    return invcount;
}

int merge(int arr[], int temp[], int l, int m, int r){
    int invcount = 0;
    int k = l;
    int i = l, j = m+1;

    while(true){
        if(i>m){
            while(j<=r){
                temp[k] = arr[j];
                k++;
                j++;
            }
            break;
        }
        else if(j>r){
            while(i<=m){
                temp[k] = arr[i];
                k++;
                i++;
            }
            break;
        }

        if(arr[i] > arr[j]){
            temp[k] = arr[j];
            k++;
            j++;
            invcount += m-i+1;
        }
        else{
            temp[k] = arr[i];
            k++;
            i++;
        }
    }

    for(i=l; i<=r; i++){
        arr[i] = temp[i];
    }
    return invcount;
}

int main(int argv, char** args)
{
    // int arr[] = {1, 20, 6, 4, 5};
    int arr[] = {2, 4, 1, 3, 5};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    int *temp = new int[n];
    printf(" Number of inversions are %d \n", mergeSort(arr, temp, 0, n-1));
    // getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: can you tag the line at witch the error happens

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` -- [Don't do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).  Include the correct headers.

Comment: Better to read [these C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: The issue is more than likely about using that stupid "bits" header instead of the real headers and messing up the `merge` function.  How about showing us where the error occurs?

Comment: Compiles and runs on my machine.  No error.  Touched up the code to fix a few warnings, so compiled without warnings.

Comment: @Eljay -- No, don't touch up anything.  Take the code as-is and attempt to compile it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is more than likely your usage of `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` and calling `merge`.

The problem is that there is a [std::merge](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge) function defined in the `<algorithm>` header, and the `<bits/stdc++.h>` header includes `<algorithm>`.  In addition, you have

`using namespace std;`

complicating the issue further.  You're actually trying to call `std::merge` instead of your own `merge` function, all due to the `std` namespace being brought into your program.  The `std::merge` function requires different argument types than the ones you are passing to your own `merge` function, thus the error.

---

The solution -- stop using `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`.  Include the proper, standard C++ header instead of this one.  The proper headers would be:

```
#include <cstdio>
```

Then you would (or should) encounter another error, that `merge` is being called, but it is not known to the compiler.  In that case, you either declare the `merge` function and place that before the `mergeSort` function

```
// declare the merge() function here
int merge(int arr[], int temp[], int l, int m, int r);

int mergeSort(int arr[], int temp[], int l, int r)
{
   int invcount = 0;
   if(l<r)  {
     int m = (l+r)/2;
     invcount += mergeSort(arr, temp, l, m);
     invcount += mergeSort(arr, temp, m+1, r);
     invcount += merge(arr, temp, l, m, r);
  }
  return invcount;
}

// implement merge() here
int merge(int arr[], int temp[], int l, int m, int r)
{
   //...
}
```

or move the entire `merge` function implementation before the `mergeSort` function.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @PaulMcKenzie. It was exactly the same issue you stated. The program was calling `std::merge` instead of my own merge. I checked it up by changing the function name and it is working fine. I guess I should better stop using the "bits" header and start using the correct headers. Thanks again.

Comment: And that was a silly mistake of not declaring the merge function before mergeSort. :p